# Existence of linear/affine subspace for a number of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$.

Let $k \le \dim V$ be a natural number. I want to show that for each k vectors $v_1, ..., v_k$ there is a linear subspace $U$ of $V$ which has dimension $k$ and contains these vectors. Also I need to find out when $U$ is unique and if it is possible to make similar statements for affine subspaces.

For the linear subspaces, I was thinking about the span of the vectors $v_1, ..., v_k$, which is a linear subspace per construction. But I don't know when this could be unique or how to transfer to affine subspaces. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: I have no information about that, where does that make a difference?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with affine spaces to help you, but I can give you a hint on unicity: observe the case $n = \dim V$. Hopefully you will see why it makes a difference.